# Camel is not intercepting SoapFault with camel-cxf correctly

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

I need help. I can't get the exception my web service is throwing and I don't know why.

I have created a simple route in camel and I want to catch fault messages from a web service as an exception with the explanation of the error.

The route is the following:

```
    onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true)
        .to("log:info")
        .process(new FailureResponseProcessor())
        .to("file:data/outbox?fileName=error.xml");

    from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")   
        .process(loggerProcessor)
        .to("cxf://http://localhost:8080/TestWebService?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"
          + "&properties.exceptionMessageCauseEnabled=true"
          + "&properties.faultStackTraceEnabled=true")
        .to("file:data/outbox?fileName=response.xml");
```

In the context configuration I have this:

```
context.setHandleFault(true);
```

The web service that I created for testing is as simple as this:

```
@WebService
public class TestWebService {
    @WebMethod
    public double suma(double a, double b) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Webservice invocado!!!");
        throw new Exception("Mi excepcion");
        //return a + b;
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to get the message from the exception "Mi excepcion".

I guess the problem comes from this line:

```
2015-04-28 13:05:15 DEBUG DefaultErrorHandler:71 - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-saqqara-40731-1430219108400-0-3 on ExchangeId: ID-saqqara-40731-1430219108400-0-2). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: No se ha encontrado el método de distribución de {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope
```

Because the caught exception is my exception policy is this one:

```
Error: No se ha encontrado el método de distribución de {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope
```

EDIT:

I have changed a little bit the code to log more info. This what I've done:

```
onException(SoapFault.class)
    .handled(true)
    .log("Response ON ERROR: ${body}")
    .log("Response ON FAULT: ${exception}")
    .process(new FailureResponseProcessor())
    .to("file:data/outbox?fileName=error.xml");

from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
    .id("miRuta")
    .log("File content: ${body}")
    .to("cxf://http://localhost:8080/TestWebService?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"
      + "&properties.exceptionMessageCauseEnabled=true"
      + "&properties.faultStackTraceEnabled=true")
    .log("WS Response: ${body}");
```

What I found is that when the exception is caught, the message that is logged with the following line:

```
.log("Response ON ERROR: ${body}")
```

is this one:

```
2015-04-29 09:53:28 INFO  route1:95 - Response ON ERROR:

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:test="http://test_ws.testing.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <test:suma>
           <arg0>?</arg0>
           <arg1>?</arg1>
        </test:suma>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When it should be the fault message, shouldn't it?.

EDIT 2

The XML reply is the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Mi excepcion</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns2:Exception xmlns:ns2="http://test_ws.testing.com/">
                    <message>Mi excepcion</message>
                </ns2:Exception>
            </detail>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: The error translated into english is: The method of distribution of {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope has not been found

Comment: Is this exception thrown and stored in soap fault part of the message.

Comment: The exception I throw with the class TestWebService gives the following soap: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>S:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Mi excepcion</faultstring><detail><ns2:Exception xmlns:ns2="http://test_ws.testing.com/"><message>Mi excepcion</message></ns2:Exception></detail></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>

Comment: I don't know if my previous comment answer your question @Namphibian in case not please tell me to try to be more precise.

Comment: Jorge could you post the reply XML in the question. The one in your comment is a bit broken so I cant say for sure where the problem is.

Comment: Thanx for the help @Namphibian. I posted the reply in EDIT2

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem.

The xml file that I was catching in:

```
from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
```

Had the following content:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="http://test_ws.testing.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <test:suma>
         <arg0>5</arg0>
         <arg1>5</arg1>
      </test:suma>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The fault was generated correctly by the testing web service but a different one saying that the method Envelope wasn't found, which is correct because the method Envelop doesn't exist in the web service. The method that exists is "suma".

So I changed the xml to the following:

```
<test:suma xmlns:test="http://test_ws.testing.com/">
  <arg0>5</arg0>
  <arg1>5</arg1>
</test:suma>
```

And I got the expected exception: "Mi excepcion".

Thanks for the help anyway!!